# Difference between Select Unique and Select Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I thought these were synonomous, but I wrote the following in Microsoft SQL:

```
Select Unique col from 
     (select col from table1 union select col from table2) alias
```

And it failed.  Changing it to

```
Select Distinct col from 
     (select col from table1 union select col from table2) alias
```

fixed it.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 183):

`SELECT UNIQUE` is old syntax supported by Oracle's flavor of SQL.  It is synonymous with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` because this is standard SQL, and `SELECT UNIQUE` is non-standard, and in database brands other than Oracle, `SELECT UNIQUE` may not be recognized at all.

Answer (score 118):

Unique is a keyword used in the Create Table() directive to denote that a field will contain unique data, usually used for natural keys, foreign keys etc.

For example:

```
Create Table Employee(   
    Emp_PKey Int Identity(1, 1) Constraint PK_Employee_Emp_PKey Primary Key,  
    Emp_SSN Numeric Not Null Unique,  
    Emp_FName varchar(16),   
    Emp_LName varchar(16) 
)
```

i.e. Someone's Social Security Number would likely be a unique field in your table, but not necessarily the primary key.

Distinct is used in the Select statement to notify the query that you only want the unique items returned when a field holds data that may not be unique.

```
Select Distinct Emp_LName
From Employee
```

You may have many employees with the same last name, but you only want each different last name.

Obviously if the field you are querying holds unique data, then the *Distinct* keyword becomes superfluous.

Comment: You may want social security numbers to be unique, but they're not. Eg: http://www.dailyfinance.com/2010/08/12/your-social-security-number-may-not-be-unique-to-you/

Answer (score 18):

select unique is not valid syntax for what you are trying to do

you want to use either select distinct or select distinctrow

And actually, you don't even need distinct/distinctrow in what you are trying to do.  You can eliminate duplicates by choosing the appropriate union statement parameters.

the below query by itself will only provide distinct values

```
select col from table1 
union 
select col from table2
```

if you did want duplicates you would have to do

```
select col from table1 
union all
select col from table2
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong, Oracle does allow you to say `select unique...`, though I'd prefer doing the standards way.

Answer (score 5):

#### Only In Oracle =>

`SELECT DISTINCT` and `SELECT UNIQUE` behave the same way. While DISTINCT is ANSI SQL standard, UNIQUE is an Oracle specific statement.

#### In other databases (like sql-server in your case) =>

`SELECT UNIQUE` is invalid syntax. `UNIQUE` is keyword for adding unique constraint on the column.

[SELECT DISTINCT](http://psoug.org/definition/DISTINCT.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Unique** was the old syntax while **Distinct** is the new syntax,which is now the Standard sql.
2. **Unique** creates a constraint that all values to be inserted must be different from the others.
   An error can be witnessed if one tries to enter a duplicate value.
   **Distinct** results in the removal of the duplicate rows while retrieving data.
3. Example:
   SELECT **DISTINCT** names FROM student ;

   CREATE TABLE Persons (
   Id varchar NOT NULL **UNIQUE**,
   Name varchar(20) );