# How to use the UNIQUE Operator SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The below Code returns error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'.
```

Code:

```
SELECT E.ename, D.dname
FROM Emp E, Dept D
WHERE UNIQUE
    (SELECT W.did
    FROM Works W
    WHERE W.did = D.did)
```

The Employee, Works, Department is a pretty self explanatory relationship. So how does one use the `UNIQUE` operator correctly in this instance?

BTW, this is the syntax shown by my professor but I cannot figure it out. I only find results for using `UNIQUE` in `CREATE TABLE` statements. I see the use of `DISTINCT`, but not `UNIQUE`

SCHEMA:

Works = {fk(`eid`),fk(primary(`did`))}

Emp = {primary(`eid`), ename, age, salary}

Dept = {primary(`did`), dname, budget, managerid}

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012 (At least I think thats the DBMS)

Comment: Ok... and `what are you trying to achieve?`

Comment: Trying to use the `UNIQUE` keyword in the `WHERE` clause, otherwise the query is totally irrelevant. By that I mean, I am not trying to achieve anything other than getting the `UNIQUE` part to work.

Comment: you need to provide 3 table relation, emp, dept & work and what is the goal that u trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

**SELECT UNIQUE** is old syntax supported by Oracle's flavor of SQL. It is synonymous with SELECT DISTINCT.

Use **SELECT DISTINCT** because this is standard SQL, and SELECT UNIQUE is non-standard, and in database brands other than Oracle, **SELECT UNIQUE** may not be recognized at all.

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336268/sql-difference-between-select-unique-and-select-distinct)

Comment: Can I not use `UNIQUE` or `DISTINCT` in the `WHERE` CLAUSE?

Comment: I dont thing Unique or DIstinct can be used in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

"WHERE UNIQUE" is not valid sql syntax that I have ever seen (over some years/products)

Your professor may be:

- a. testing you
- b. using "pseudo code"
- c. thinking in logic terms, not    precise sql
- ... ...
- z. incorrectly noted?

a predicate isn't formed here either, what is being compared to what to produce true/false?

& Your Prof would also be advised to use ANSI join syntax

```
SELECT E.ename, D.dname
FROM Emp E
INNER JOIN Dept D ON /* what? */
WHERE /* what? could it be EXISTS ?*/
 exists
    (SELECT W.did
    FROM Works W
    WHERE W.did = D.did)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical operator in the SQL standard called UNIQUE. It evaluates to true if all the tuples in its input are distinct.

But it is not implemented in any version of SQL server I know of