# Select Column if Unique in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to only select the value of a column if it is unique.

Example of data in table:

```
 Name    City       Age
 -----------------------
 James   New York   20
 Charles New York   21
 Tom     New York   22
```

Example of output of select all query:

```
 Name    City       Age
 -----------------------
 James   New York   20
 Charles New York   21
 Tom     New York   22
```

But if Charles lived in London I want no city to be printed or a default value.

Example of data in table:

```
 Name    City       Age
 ------------------------ 
 James   New York   20
 Charles Londen     21
 Tom     New York   22
```

Example of output of a select all query.

```
 Name    City       Age
 -----------------------
 James   /          20
 Charles /          21
 Tom     /          22
```

I hope you can make the sql magic happen...

I tried doing it with a case structure but without any success. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Why don't you add desired output example and what you have tried?

Comment: What is your DB engine?

Comment: this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336268/sql-difference-between-select-unique-and-select-distinct) would be helpful to you

Comment: What is "/" supposed to be? You just replaced New York with "/". I don't see how that clarifies anything.

Comment: So if there was a fourth record with Charles in London what would the result be? Can you update your post with that?

Comment: New York isn't unique in your current example, it appears 3 times. Do you mean that you only want it displayed if all the records match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a join to other cities, and mask duplicates:

```
select distinct
    p.name,
    case when p2.city is not null then null else p.city end city,
    p.age
from person p
left join person p2 on p.name = p2.name
   and p.city != p2.city
```

`distinct` makes only one row result for duplicate cities.

This query relies on the age being consistent for a given name between cities. If it's not, use something like `max(age)`  and group by the other columns.

To provide a default value instead of `null` for duplicates, change `then null` to `then 'Various'` (eg).

Comment: Yes, that is the end of the case statement and then the column is given the alias of `city`

Comment: @giannischristofakis yes. The "city" on the end is a column alias (it names the column that the result of the case produces)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the accepted answer addresses OP's question, because it only checks the uniqueness across the cities of person with the same name. It also doesn't satisfy the second provided dataset.

The following query checks the uniqueness **across the entire column** and satisfies the example output for the inputs provided by OP.

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  CASE
    WHEN stats.unique_cities > 1 THEN '/'
    ELSE p.city
  END city,
  p.age
FROM person p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city) unique_cities FROM person) stats;
```

`CROSS JOIN` (ANSI-92 syntax) could also be replaced with the `,` syntax (ANSI-89 syntax), i.e. `FROM person p, (SELECT ...`.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this -
select name,
case when
(select count(distinct id) from myt)>1
then 7
else
ID
end as id
from myt
group by id,name

table myt - name, id