# Database query UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to PL SQL. I would like to fetch data on the basis of some unique attribute. May I use the UNIQUE keyword in WHERE clause? If yes then what would be the exact syntax.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: PL/SQL as in the Oracle programming language?

Comment: Thank you for the answers..
But I was trying to say that I want to fetch attributes on the basis of a unique column..It is not the unique column that I'm trying to fetch..
I want something like-> Select column_name from table where column_name1 is unique..                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Is it possible??

Comment: David Aldridge- Yes..

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for using `UNIQUE`:

```
SELECT UNIQUE <column_name_list> FROM <table_name> WHERE <conditions>;
```

However, consider using the keyword `DISTINCT` for selecting unique values as `UNIQUE` is not standard across all SQL databases.

```
SELECT DISTINCT <column_name_list> FROM <table_name> WHERE <conditions>;
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336268/difference-between-select-unique-and-select-distinct) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To select only the unique values from a certain column, all you have to do is: 
`SELECT UNIQUE columnName FROM tableName;`