# Need to avoid repetition results in sql table

Tags: sql-server

I have written a SQL command to get the different entries from two tables. But table 3 is not a steady one it fills one by one (It has a dynamic nature because it is filled by a RFID reader). So the difference table (table2) has multiple entries of same. Please help to avoid this adding same entries.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (EPC)
  SELECT PL.EPC
  FROM   priorityLevel PL
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    table3 T3
    WHERE   PL.EPC = T3.EPC
  );
```

I expect not to repeat same entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Select Unique and Select Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336268/difference-between-select-unique-and-select-distinct)

Comment: Why don't you just add a DISTINCT ?.  ... ... select distinct PL.EPC ... ...

Comment: It not clear what you like to accomplished. Usually Dale edited the question and translate to understandable form.

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic- I need to get different entries by comparing two tables. prioritylevel  has 5 entries which is given by me.Table 3 is filling by in put from a RFID reader (Like a bar code reader). So it is in a dynamic environment. So repetition results are occurs . I need to avoid it.

Comment: @MarcGuillot distinct can't help this matter because the issue happens there are iterations in data entry in table3.

Comment: @jithmasenarathne Why don't you provide some sample data showing the problem ?.

Comment: Table1  00 00 00 01  <br/> 00 00 00 02  <br/> 00 00 00 03  <br/> 00 00 00 04  <br/>   <br/> Table3  <br/> 00 00 00 01  <br/> 00 00 00 02  <br/>  <br/> Table2  <br/> 00 00 00 02  <br/> 00 00 00 03  <br/> 00 00 00 04  <br/> 00 00 00 03  <br/>00 00 00 04

Comment: Simply table1 (1,2,3,4)   table 3(1,2)   table2(2,3,4,3,4)

Comment: @MarcGuillot   ...

Comment: @jithmasenarathne Edit your question and add the sample there instead of comment.

Comment: And try to explain why you have three tables holding the same data more or less

Comment: @Jonny- This is a small part of a project. All I need is to get the different entries without duplicating.Can you modify a code for it.